# How to use a looping function to update python Kivy application

Tags: python, function, loops, kivy

I have created a program that is based on a **looping function**. Every time it loops I want to update two labels in the screen. The problem is I use a button to call the function and it does not update the labels until the function stops executing. Lest say I have a label and I call a looping functions that adds from 0 to infinity. I want the label to update in every number. Is this possible?

EDIT: the problem solved using Clock.schedule_interval(function, time) (time in seconds) Just a simple app that adds a number every second and displays it to the screen

Code:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from time import sleep


class Window(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Window, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1
        self.cnt = 0
        self.btn = Button(text='Start')
        self.add_widget(self.btn)
        self.btn.bind(on_press=self.pressed)
        self.lbl = Label()
        self.add_widget(self.lbl)

    def starting(self, instance):
        self.lbl.text = str(self.cnt)
        self.cnt += 1
        sleep(1)

    def pressed(self, instance):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.starting, 0)


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Window()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: Post the code..

Comment: What have you done so far? What went wrong with your attempts? See this link on how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've written code that starts looping, then does nothing else until the looping is done. Instead you need to write code that loops once, then lets the gui update, then is run again some time later.

This is straightforward using `Clock.schedule_interval`:

```
Clock.schedule_interval(your_function, time_delta)  # time_delta is in seconds, the function is run whenever this amount of time has elapsed
```

The `your_function` should perform a single iteration of your loop.

Comment: can I repeat the function as soon as it ends or I should specify an interval?